# Javascript function after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call to a JavaScript function that is sent in a Ajax call

What is the correct way to execute a JavaScript function returned from an Ajax call?

Let say the script looks like this before the Ajax call

```
<script>
 function start(){
   console.log('1');
 }
</script>
```

I receive

```
<script>
 function start(){
   console.log('2');
 }
</script>
```

Here is the code I have now

```
nav = $('.js-as'),
$content = $('.js-content'),
$status  = $('.js-status'),
$script  = $('.js-script'),

$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax',
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
      if (isSupported('transition')) $status.removeClass('start done');

      fadeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
          if (isSupported('transition')) $status.addClass('start');
      }, 100); // Avoid fadeTimer() if content already in cache
  },
  success: function(data) {
      if (fadeTimer) clearTimeout(fadeTimer);

      $nav.removeClass('selected');
      stateLink(e, 'active');
      handler(data);
  }
});
handler = function(data) { // Response
  d.title = data.pagetitle;
  $content.html(data.content);
  $script.html(data.script); // my new script 
  eval(start()); // execute it
};
```

UPDATE: Solution
Using jQuery.globalEval solved this issue

Comment: Can you paste your AJAX call and the above code in the same context so we can understand your question more...

Comment: So, what's wrong with your code? What isn't working?

Comment: after ajax call the script changes to console.log('2'); but calling start() return 1

Comment: add `async: false` as an option to your `$.ajax()` call, try it again, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Debugging 101- remove EVERYTHING except the AJAX call and the data you're getting in and out, and `console.log()` that data from the response and within the handler. Still not sure what your problem is, so remove your top two examples and replace it with your real code that's the problem - in it's barest form :)

Comment: You mean you want to execute data.script

Comment: I rewrote the question to reflect your actual question. Your assumptions about Ajax are wrong. You cannot change the html of a script tag. You need to use [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for example instead

Comment: Using jQuery.globalEval solved this issue

Comment: This is a huge security problem in your application. Careful.

Comment: why? I tried also getScript but no success

Answer (score 0):

Use one function with argument.

Something like that:

```
<script>
function start(num){
console.log(num);
}
</script>
```

So before the AJAX call tou can call `start(1)` and after the AJAX call you can call `start(2)`

Comment: Thanks but my purpose is not console log, I mean in genarally, how to change the function that after ajax call the function would do what inside this

Comment: You all misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = function(){
  console.log(1);
}
```

After ajax calling

```
start = function(){
  console.log(2);
}
start();
// output "2"
```

Comment: You all misunderstood the question

Comment: @mplungjan i understand like that: we must replace context of function. If its wrong can you explain?